# Microsoft teams conditionals broken when hiding requisite field

Tags: css, microsoft-teams

My code runs like this:

```
"background-color": 
    "=if([$col1] >
    [$col2], 'lightpink', 'palegreen')"
```

And it works fine until I hide col2 in the Teams View. Then some of the fields that were pink turn green. Is this a bug?

[see center row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgHJB.png)

[with column hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKMMZ.png)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your requirement for Teams View and share the docs which you are following?

Comment: I don't understand the question you are asking me. I was able to fix this by requesting the .displayValue... however, this seems inconsistent as it fails on a different column on a different list as that only works properly when no .displayValue is called.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ You should edit your post question and add the extra information in your above comment to it, so that everyone is sure to read these details _ Please take some time to visit SO Help Center, and specifically the section on 'Asking' to find out more about how to post questions more effectively >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking